# Stretch a block container to the same height as another block container

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to stretch a block container to the same height as the surrounding block, or at least to match the height of the inline-container next to it.

This is my xsl code with blindtext:

```
<fo:block margin="0" padding="0" font-size="9pt"  border="thin solid silver" >
    <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="60%" display-align="after">
        <fo:block border="thin solid blue">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container>
    <fo:inline-container inline-progression-dimension="5%" text-align="right"  >
        <fo:block-container height="50px" width="5mm" display-align="before"  margin-left="5px" border-style="solid" border-width="1pt" background-color="red" border-color="white" fox:border-radius="4pt">
            <fo:block>
                &#160;
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
    </fo:inline-container>
</fo:block>
```

And this is the resulting pdf:
[image: resulting pdf]

I want the red box to be always the same height as the textbox. The `&#160;` is an empty character, otherwise the line height will go upwards, instead of downwards. 
It would be possible with a border on the text block, but it has to have the rounded edges and i'm not sure how to do it otherwise.

Can i somehow dynamically adjust the height for this? Or is there another way to display a round cornered line that adjusts its size to the text block?

Comment: Put that block container in another one and set it's right border with some pad

Comment: The right border on an `fo:block-container` won't have the required four rounded corners.  I came close using AH Formatter and an `fo:table`, but AFAICT, FOP doesn't do rounded corners on `fo:table-cell`, so I couldn't get it to work with FOP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be doing change bars. If that is the case, there are engine specific extensions to XSL-FO that might be useful to you.

Try checking out http://services.renderx.com/Content/support/xep/reference.html#Change_Bars